# Angular Could not install ESLint, it does not contain a package.json file

Tags: angular-cli, eslint, lint

I really like lint.  I love that the CLI has built-in lint, but it is being deprecated.  I use Windows 10 Pro.  Per the Quick Start, I tried the first step and it failed as follows:

```
> npm i -g @angular-devkit/{core,schematics} @angular-eslint/schematics
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "@angular-devkit\{core,schematics}" as it does not contain a package.json file.
```

Quick Start:
https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint#migrating-from-codelyzer-and-tslint

How can I install ESLint globally or locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full first step of installing **eslint** (per the URL in the question) is as follows:

```
npm i -g @angular/cli @angular-devkit/{core,schematics} @angular-eslint/schematics
```

I am not familiar with *{core,schematics}* but that seems to cause a problem (as per the error message).  When I executed the **NPM** installs separately as follows:

```
> npm i -g @angular-devkit/core
> npm i -g @angular-eslint/schematics
```

It didn't cause an error.  I hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

if you need eslint, install it
npm I -g eslint